# Jersey - Marshal Object from HTTP Headers

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to have Jersey take a series of HTTP headers and marshall them into a POJO, much as one might do with POST parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get access to a specific `@HeaderParam` as a `String`, use the answers provided by @Juned Ahsan or @DJ Spiess. If you want to inject them into a POJO, I would recommend using Jersey's [`@BeanParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) in 2.x.

For example:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public void bar(@BeanParam MyBean myBean) {
      // Do something
    }
}

public class MyBean {
    private String uaCompatible;

    public MyBean(@HeaderParam("X-UA-Compatible") String uaCompatible) {
        this.uaCompatible = uaCompatible;
    }

    public String getUacompatible() {
        return this.uaCompatible;
    }
}
```

`@BeanParam` can be replaced with `@InjectParam` for Jersey 1.x (>=1.4) or `@Inject` in 1.x earlier than 1.4. javax-`@Inject` can also be used if you're using a dependency injection framework such as Spring.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, as I'll need to create a composite entity from three different headers!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jersey 1.x then you can use @InjectParam,
But I would suggest you to upgrade to 2.x and start using @BeanParam

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd do it like this.  (from http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/)

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

@GET
@Path("/get")
public Response addUser(@HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {
        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, userAgent : " + userAgent)
            .build();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so using the `@HeaderParams`